# Programming NXT ultrasonic sensor with EV3 software

Tags: ev3, nxt

How can I program the NXT ultrasonic sensor with EV3 software? When I pick the block for the ultrasonic sensor, it tells me it is not compatible.

Comment: Are you using an NXT brick or an EV3 brick?

Comment: I guess you have NXT hardware and EV3 software. The answer is to download the bricks as software as described [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8571/ev3-ultrasonic-sensor-block-is-not-availible-in-the-home-edition-software).