# EV3 Ultrasonic Sensor block is not availible in the Home Edition software

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, ev3-g

I can't find the ultrasonic sensor block on the programming app on my computer. I am using the Lego Mindstorms EV3 Home Edition.

Answer (score 6):

You can download the Ultrasonic sensor block (and Gyro sensor too) from the [official MINDSTORMS website](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/about).

Look for "Ultrasonic Sensor Block" near the bottom of the [downloads page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads).

Comment: And then import the downloaded file within your EV3 Home Edition.

Comment: Can we not just get the teacher edition for Mac OS. I though this was supposed to be simple for kids. Downloading plugins is no simple. Where can I find the teacher edition for Mac OS?

Comment: Since November 2019, LEGO has a new scratch-based programming software for macOS. It includes the Ultrasonic and Gryo sensors in all versions (home and edu).

Comment: Link is outdated

Comment: Links are fixed now, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I have downloaded the Ultrasonic block (on a mac) but cannot figure out how to install it, any ideas?

Comment: You can find a tutorial for installing the blocks here: https://ev3lessons.com/en/ProgrammingLessons/beginner/ImportingBlocks.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Lego changed their website for LEGO MINDSTORMS, so you can download all needed stuff for EV3 or NXT from here: https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads